# How to change the background color for dialog to black

Tags: linux, shell, dialog

I am invoking a dialog with the following command:

```
dialog --inputbox "test" 20 0
```

I have set the screen color background color to BLACK:

```
screen_color = (WHITE,BLACK,OFF)
```

But the color is an off-black not black:

[image]

Comment: can you pass these as args to dialog or does it only work in a .dialogrc file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing this has to do with the colors you have set in your terminal. If you run the following command you can verify.

```
echo -e "\033[0;40m                   "
```

This will print out spaces with a black background. If you wish it to be total black you will need to change what color "black" is in the terminals config.

What you're wanting is the "default" terminal color. To get that replace `BLACK` with `DEFAULT`.

Comment: When I print `\033[0;40m` I get the off-black. What then is the name for `\033[0;0m` which is the black that I want?

Comment: `\033[0;0m` (or just `\033m[0m` is actually "reset" which generally means white text on the color of the terminal. You can try to use the color `DEFAULT` in place of `BLACK` in order to get the "default" color of your terminal. Note that this will not always be black, though. This will be whatever background color the users terminal is. The same could be said for `BLACK` though since you can change that to whatever color you wish.

Comment: To add to `Note that this will not always be black, though.` it is common for a terminal's background color to be white, for example. But this may be what you want!

Comment: That's it! Thank you. :)

Comment: Sweet! No problem. I'll update my answer to include the info.